# How to distribute a Java desktop application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What is the alternative to distributing Java?

I don't want to add [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Overview) in my extracted files.
I don't want to  give away my .jar file to the user.
The end user just install and use application.

Which database to use so that the user don't need to configure like SQL Server.

How to decrease execution time of my application? It takes more time to execute.

**Edit**

It is an application without a database.
There should be a setup file which installs in `Program Files` and shortcut on the desktop and some registry entry to start it with start up application.

Comment: First part is a duplicate. Please split the other two questions so that they can be handled separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deliver Java desktop apps as [Applets](http://java.sun.com/applets/) and (more recently) [Java Web Start](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp) apps. Using these technologies means that users don't need to manually handle files.

As for RDBMS, there is a pure Java RDBMS going by the names [JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/) and [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) which might meet your needs.

There are many ways to improve the execution time of a program, it depends on what you've coded and what it does, for a start. I think you'll need to ask a specific question on that to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Web Start](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp) works well as a distribution mechanism. Host the .jar on your site and your clients can download (provided they have a JRE). It'll select the appropriate JRE to use and allow you to update the application at your end with automatic downloads.

If you want a database, check out [JavaDB](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/). It's pure Java and comes as standard with Java 6. Your application can check for an existing db on start-up, and initialise/configure if not present. That will then remain for future invocations.